# ¿Cómo hacer que una aplicación web se ejecute permanentemente en una instancia de lightsails (aws)?

Tags: nodejs, aws, procesos-en-segundo-plano

Tengo una web estática desplegada en lightsails de aws, el problema es que si cierro la ventana de la consola de la conexión a mi instancia (interrumpliendose el proceso) al poner la dirección en el navedaor: MIIP:MIPUERTO ya no me entrega la web, no me la carga en el navegador. He pensado ejecutar el proceso en segundo plano pero al cerrar la ventana de la consola sigo teniendo el mismo problema. Yo entiendo que una aplicacion web debe de tener una disponibilidad permanente.

He probado con `nohup node miapp.js &` y si que me la manda a segundo plano, pero como ya he dicho, al cerrar la ventana de la consola el proceso, aunque en segundo plano, también está interrumpido.

Comment: Deberías crear un servicio, ¿Cuál sistema operativo tiene tu instancia?.

Comment: @Sal: Mi instancia tiene linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo encontré. Hay que poner:

```
forever node app.js
```

donde app.js es el punto de entrada en el backend.